# Does the GPC polygon clipper do triangulation?

Tags: c++, c, triangulation

I was looking at this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981161/gpc-polygon-initialization) in regards to this library. However it is still unclear to me if this library can do like glu tesselator does and return a series of triangles which I can then render with OpenGL. If it can do this, how is this done? I'm just not clear on this from reading the docs. So essentially what i'm trying to find out is, if it can in fact triangulate, once I add my contours, how do I get the triangle verticies so I can render them with opengl?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPC will either produce contour (polygon boundary) output, or will give a result as a series of triangle strips for the solid rendering of polygon interiors. Two functions select between the two kinds of output: gpc_polygon_clip() and gpc_tristrip_clip(). Cheers, --Toby Howard, GPC Licensing Manager.

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate on the first one(gpc_polygon_clip() )Does it return a series of triangles to render like GLUTesselator or is it just a contour of verticies for an outline?